# Can't finding TD's DIV using EvaluateXPath Method in TestComplete

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

**Using TestComplete-10.20.953.7**

My scenario is like this..

```
<tr>
  <td>
  <td>
    <div>requirdText</div>
  <td>
  <td>
    <div>STATUS</div>
  <td>
  .
  .
  .

</tr>
```

I am trying to use `EvaluateXPath` method to find the `"STATUS"` if page contains `"requiredText"`

Here is my XPath..

```
Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Run("http://xxx/yyy/#zzzz:A-BC-");

var page = Sys.Browser("*").Page("*");

var obj = page.EvaluateXPath("//*[contains(text(), '" + text+ "')]/../../td[4]/div");

if ( obj !== null && obj !== undefined ) {

  var status = obj[0].innerText;
  Log.Message(status);
}
```

**When i run the script it gives me below error...**

`'0.innerText' is null or not an object`

Any idea what might possible be gone wrong or how can i my expected resut?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Updated my question with more info.

Comment: Did you read my question carefully i clearly mention in the subject also in the first line that I am "Using TestComplete-10.20.953.7"

Comment: I am using JavaScript in TestComplete for test automation.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  Try using chrome/firefox to test this on step through the code in the console.  You should be able to see what `obj` is.  Perhaps you are having issues with the fact that your `td` elements aren't being closed? Without the test framework and more code I cannot help any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the EvaluateXPath result to a JScript-compatible array:

```
var obj = page.EvaluateXPath(...);

if (obj != null) {
  obj = obj.toArray();
  ...
}
```

Or, you can use FindChildByXPath instead - it returns a single object instead of an array.